jOOQ adds backticks to PostgreSQL statement
Just wanted to try out jOOQ 3.19.6 with PostgreSQL and get stuck with this simple query
dsl.select(asterisk()).from(TEST_TABLE).fetch();

Output:
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select * from `public`.`test_table`]; ERROR: syntax error at or near "`"

As far as I know, PostgreSQL doesn't use backticks this way. So why is jOOQ placing them there instead of double quotes? How can I fix this?

I Found the problem:
dsl = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MARIADB);

should be:
DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.POSTGRES);

